# How should I associate models via geography intersections with postgis and rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgis

I'm using Rails 3.1.4, postgis, and activerecord-postgis-adapter. I have a "Zcta" model and a "Neighborhood" model, and each has a "geog" column. I want to find  intersections, such as all neighborhoods that intersect a certain zip code, or all zip codes that intersect a certain neighborhood. I can do that with an explicit join like this:

```
Zcta.joins("join neighborhoods on st_intersects(zcta.geog, neighborhoods.geog)").where("neighborhoods.name" => 'Silver Lake')
```

Rails creates a single SQL query from this that returns all the appropriate Zcta objects based on intersection with a neighborhood. This is nice, but I don't get to retrieve the neighborhood object in the same query. It's also kind of unwieldy. What I'm looking for is more like a has_many relationship that can be eager loaded. Something like this:

```
Neighborhood.find(name: 'Silver Lake').include(:zctas)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Rails?